# Ansible - How to run multiple tasks in a playbook

Tags: ansible

I'm new to ansible, and am attempting to run multiple tasks to install docker on a particular host group in an ansible playbook.

I have the following playbook...

```
---
 - hosts: all
   tasks:
    - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
      become: yes
      apt:
        upgrade: yes
        update_cache: yes
        cache_valid_time: 86400 #One day

 - hosts: loadbalancer
   become: yes
   tasks:
    - name: Install docker packages
      apt:
        name:
        - 'apt-transport-https'
        - 'ca-certificates'
        - 'curl'
        - 'software-properties-common'
        state: present

    - name: Add Docker official GPG key
      apt-key:
        url: https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg
```

This is the error I get when attempting to run the playbook...

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/vagrant/ansible/playbooks/hostname.yml': line 23, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: Add Docker official GPG key
      ^ here
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: Your playbook does not respect yaml and/or ansible syntax. Please [take Y minutes to learn yaml](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/) and pay attention to indentation and new lines. You can validate your playbooks with [yamllint](https://yamllint.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [ansible-lint](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-lint/) prior to posting. Specific `ansible-lint` error on your above playbook: `Couldn't parse task at playbook.yml:23 (couldn't resolve module/action 'apt-key'. This often indicates a misspelling, missing collection, or incorrect module path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not `apt-key`, it is `apt_key`. Please update and try again